# NTFS HDD as a data storage for docker containers

Tags: ntfs, docker

I have a NTFS HDD on which I have various `docker-compose` setups (e.g. postgres). The NTFS HDD is mounted as NTFS from Ubuntu and when I bind a folder from the HDD into a docker container, when the container wants to do `chown` or `chmod` it gets `Operation not permitted`.

Many docker images (as per good practices) will use a non-`root` user to run so they need to have the appropriate permissions on their directories. And those directories I want bound to the host file system, and not named volumes.

Here are my constraints:

- I want the HDD to remain NTFS.
- I would prefer to use file system mounts so that I can store the data of the containers alongside with their configuration on this HDD.

Comment: NTFS does not support normal Linux ownership permissions. You have to specify them in the mount command or in fstab and they apply globally across all directories and files. There are plenty of Q&A’s on here about how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I tried this - the point is that even if you mount with some `umask` the permissions still can't be modified further - e.g. in my case when a container wants to `chmod` or `chown` a directory

Comment: There is no way round that except use a Linux filesystem

Comment: Not sure how much of the same situation it is, but somehow WSL2 under windows managed to tackle this problem. In fact, the very same setup works with docker for windows over WSL2 with Ubuntu

Comment: That’s probably because there would be a translation layer between WSL2 and the underlying Windows system that manages the file storage which would be provided by Windows. That would have to exist to have WSL2 in the first place